# What is causing this "Access Denied" error?

Tags: spring-security

I'm getting an "Access Denied" error when I run [this Postman request](https://github.com/paul-reiners/ecommerce-application/blob/4498ebc4788e19af57c8e5d7194cc27c7251f82f/postman/Udacity.postman_collection.json#L9).

[image]

Here is my security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationVerificationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

And the constant is

```
public static final String SIGN_UP_URL = "api/user/create";
```

My entire project is [here](https://github.com/paul-reiners/ecommerce-application).

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Also if you add `/` at the signup URL it would fix the issue on your current spring boot version

Comment: Upgrading Spring Boot to 2.3.4 didn't help.  Neither did adding the ending slash.

Comment: I ran your project locally and its working fine for me.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? did you re-load the dependencies and compile the project(IDE should compile automatically) but give it a try.

Comment: I'm using ItelliJ IDEA.  I invalidated the caches and restarted.  Maybe I should try rebooting my computer.

Comment: :D no i think that would be unnecessary. Here are some tests that says appending / at the beginning would solve the problem. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcherTests.java

Comment: I also wrote a test myself to demonstrate that. 
```@Test
    public void a() {
        AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

        assertThat(pathMatcher.match("api/user/create", "/api/user/create")).isTrue(); //fails
        assertThat(pathMatcher.match("/api/user/create", "/api/user/create")).isTrue();
    }```

Comment: Also, please try putting a breakpoint on `org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher#match` and start your app in debug mode and let me know what are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Beginning slash is missing from the SIGN_UP_URL...